# Java program runs yet compilation fails

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I wrote a Java program whose filename was (intentionally) different from the class I wrote inside the file. The javac command failed as expected on both CMD and WSL. The java command however worked and ran my print statement. I wrote the code intentionally this way so there is no way it was a previously compiled version of the code. The following code was written in a file called "explainJava.java" (notice the filename is different from the class name).

```
public class explain{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Java is weird");
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please show your command line interactions in the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have the above code written in a file called explainJava.java, in command line (for both Command Prompt and Windows Subsystem for Linux) I first call "javac explainJava.java" which fails; I then call "java explainJava.java" which works fine.

Comment: reminder that, in addition to posting the code, you should also include how you are running the code (which commands, ex: `javac explain.java`) as well as the specific error you're encountering. in my answer below I included the error message, which is quite clear: `class explain is public, should be declared in a file named explain.java`

Answer (score 0):

I've had to google this myself, but I think I've found an explanation in [this article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/).

According to that source as of Java 11 `java` is capable of compiling a **single source file** into memory.

What I conclude from that: When the file is compiled into memory and not written to disk it obviously cannot have a file name. If there is no filename there is no such thing as a wrong filename, therefore the code executes.

Please also note that the restriction of having to name a file like the public class within that file is more of a design decision to make work for the compiler easier/ faster. It is not a **physical restriction** so to speak. Have a look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-are-filenames-in-java-the-same-as-the-public-class-name) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this code:

```
public class explain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java is weird");
    }
}
```

into a file named `explainJava.java`, and then compile it with this:

```
javac explainJava.java
```

you will get an error that correctly informs you that your filename ("explainJava") and the class defined inside that file ("explain") do not match:

```
explainJava.java:1: error: class explain is public, should be declared in a file named explain.java
public class explain{
       ^
1 error
```

If you run this command:

```
$ java explainJava.java 
Java is weird
```

you see expected output, because you're skipping the explicit compilation step (that is, you aren't running `javac` first) and instead relying on behavior introduced in Java 11 that allows you to compile+run in a single step. Here's an explanation: [Does the 'java' command compile Java programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086412/does-the-java-command-compile-java-programs/58086598#58086598)

So the answer is to either:

- rename your *file* to match the class, so change the filename to "explain.java", or
- rename the *class* to match the file, change `public class explain` to be `public class explainJava`